# Exception when VS 2010 ASP.NET Development Server Serves Static Files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, cassini

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC 2 site with Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2.

Out of nowhere none of my images or css started showing up.  If I navigate directly to the resources in the browser I see this exception message:

> Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   utcDate

Stack Trace:

> [ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name:
>   utcDate]
>   System.Web.HttpCachePolicy.UtcSetLastModified(DateTime
>   utcDate) +3038942
>   System.Web.StaticFileHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context, String overrideVirtualPath)
>   +1130    System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +347
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +8683736    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +184

Some Notes:

Already tried restarting vs 2010, closing all the webserver instances, restarting IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by setting my computer's clock data way into the future, build the project in debug mode, and then moved the time back.

From googling around I found this is because your trying to load assemblies that were last modified in the future.  Time travel coding basically.

The other problem I had was once I set the time into the future, my VS2010 evaluation period expired.

---

Lol, this was because of daylight savings time which I completely forgot about.