# Why is performance is slow when 2010 Cassini serves static files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cassini

When running a site in debug mode on 2010 I get incredible slow performance when cassini serves static files.  According to Firebug it takes about 1 seconds for each request to resolve on 20 2kb images.

I haven't changed any settings, just have done a straight up install followed by converting a couple of projects.   Rebooted the computer, reloaded IIS without solving anything.

I did have a different problem which I asked about on stackoverflow.com:
[Exception when VS 2010 ASP.NET Development Server Serves Static Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1656487/exception-when-vs-2010-cassini-serves-static-files)

Are my problems related?

Any ideas on what could be wrong or should I try a reinstall?

Update: This is not specific to any browser, all of them are just as slow as loading my resources.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the accepted answer on this question, which is highly relevant if you're using Firefox as your browser:

[ASP.NET MVC on Cassini: How can I force the "content" directory to return 304s instead of 200s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795451/asp-net-mvc-on-cassini-how-can-i-force-the-content-directory-to-return-304s-in)