# Very slow loading time with Visual Studio and ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, webserver

**hi,**

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC website with Visual Studio 2010. The site is built and running from the local computer with the local built-in ASP.NET Development Server, the database is located somwhere on the net.

The problem is that it is very slow to load or reload the page, take a look on this sceen :

[image]
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rrfsb.jpg)

Any idea why this is that slow?

BestRegards

Edit : I have found out that this do only happen i Firefox, IE will return the page ALOT faster?

Comment: I had the same issue a while ago.  The local web server was taking forever to serve static files.  Unfortunately I never found a solution and the problem went away after a while: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664855/why-is-performance-is-slow-when-2010-cassini-serves-static-files

Comment: @jfar, Thanks, that did not help. But I tried IE8 and its MUCH faster, even the ajax calls is so fast that the loading icon do not show? Why is firefox so slow?

Comment: Don't know.  You should probably edit your question with more details about which browser is doing this.  In my case it was happening on any browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codewut.de/content/local-iis-dev-server-firefox-slow-request-response-times

> If you run into the same issue, disable IPv6 support in Firefox:
>   about:config -> network.dns.disableIPv6 -> true
>   Apparently Firefox and Microsoft Internet Information Server do not like to play together nicely on Vista without human intervention.

More details (and links at bottom):
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/12/29/why-are-scripts-slow-to-load-in-firefox-when-using-visual-studio-s-built-in-development-web-server-a-k-a-cassini.aspx

Give this a try, let me/us know if it helps!  I've heard a lot about this issue.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. Its a really big difference.

Comment: for  me trying `Mr. James` **solution** from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4969403) worked, hope helps someone.

Answer (score 8):

## Quick Fix

Just change

```
http://localhost:XXXX/YourSite/Here
```

To

```
http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/YourSite/Here
```

Much better IMO than disabling IPv6 settings in Firefox, what if you want to use IPv6?

## More Permanent Solution

If you want a slightly more permanant solution, you can edit your hosts file, normally `C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows, and add a rule for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

## Customising Firefox Specifically

<strike>If you do decide you want to disable IPv6 in Firefox itself, there are details of that here:
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.dns.disableIPv6</strike>

Edit: Actually, if you want to fix this in Firefox, rather than disabling IPv6 entirely as in the link I just posted, or as specified by the other answer to this question, give this a read:
http://theycallmemrjames.blogspot.com/2010/09/firefox-is-really-slow-testing-sites-on.html
This shows how to set a rule for localhost to only use IPv4, so your browser may still use IPv6 as it needs.