# ASP.NET MVC website is too slow on localhost (screenshot of firebug is attached.You can see all requests )

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, optimization, architecture

I have developed website in Asp.net MVC 4.0 and deployed on local IIS.
But it's too slow. It takes more then 2 minutes to load page.(screeshot attached). Same behavior with every page/link

**How can I speed up my site.?**

I'm using

*01 - Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate (Same behavious on Visual Studio 2013)

02 - IIS 7.5

03 - Running site on firfox, Inspecting in firebug

04 - OS is Windows 7 ultimate

05 - RAM 8 GM (more then 3 free)

06 - Core i5*

My other Asp.net websites run fine on my system and other applications as well. Only problem is in this Website.

How can I speed up this. because with this speed I'm not able to do development or debug code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could be related to IPv6. Try to comment out the definition for the IPv6 address for localhost in your hosts file, flush the DNS cache and restart your browser.

A quick check is to use http://127.0.0.1 instead of http://localhost.

If you have a database connection string, try to change it to 127.0.0.1 as well.

Comment: @code: Same response.I have replaced localhost with 127.0.0.1. So new url will be 
http://127.0.0.1/MyProject/Home/ResetPassword

Comment: There is already a rule/entry "127.0.0.1 localhost" in my host file

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been fixed by disabling Elmah and log4net in webconfig file.
The load time reduced to 2.06 seconds from 2 minutes .

I was facing issue in firefox and chrome as well.
I tried Codo(user who answered above) solution but it didn't work for me.
I also tried the steps that explained in following url but this also didn't work for me.
 
[Very slow loading time with Visual Studio and ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237340/very-slow-loading-time-with-visual-studio-and-asp-net-mvc?rq=1)